# Vaadin load another view via Link?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Please tell me, is it possible that.

I have a Link.

```
Link jobNameLink = new Link(jobName, new ExternalResource("opla"));
```

I need to when you click on this link to download a different view.
If not possible, what are the possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: yes
I hope that the example of the link that led me below what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options:

Use Button instead of Link:

```
Button button = new Button("Click me!", new Button.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        // Logic for opening correct view
    }
});
button.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
```

Or listen URI fragment changes by using UriFragmentUtility (Vaadin 6) or UriFragmentChangedListener (Vaadin 7) and then you can use a normal link: Here's an example with Vaadin 7:

```
Page.getCurrent().addUriFragmentChangedListener(new Page.UriFragmentChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void uriFragmentChanged(Page.UriFragmentChangedEvent e) {
         System.out.println("fragment changed: " + e.getUriFragment());
    }
});


new Link("click me!", new ExternalResource("#asdf"))
```

Comment: I think that the example of the link is what I need. Thank you!